# Is $\omega = \theta d\theta + zdz$ one 1-form in $S^2$ with cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: differential-geometry

Take the $S^2$ sphere with cylindrical coordinates. We now that $\alpha = d\theta\wedge dz$ is the symplectic form of this manifold, with $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ and $z \in (-1,1)$ . Following the same mentality, if I take $\omega = \theta d\theta + zdz$ this is a $1-$form on $S^2$?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a word, "no", $\omega = \theta\, d\theta + z\, dz$ is not a $1$-form on the entire $2$-sphere $S^{2}$.

On the region $0 \leq \theta < 2\pi$ and $-1 < z < 1$, your expression $\omega$ is indeed a $1$-form, though it's discontinuous along the arc $\theta = 0$ because the longitude function $\theta$ itself is discontinuous where $\theta = 0$.

The expression $\omega$ is not well-defined at the poles $z = \pm 1$, however, because $d\theta$ is not well-defined at $z = \pm 1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ok, this is not a $1-$form defined on the entire sphere, but, is this defined at least in some open set over the sphere? I mean, locally, this 1-form is in $T^{\ast}S^2$? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, it's a (discontinuous) $1$-form on the complement of two points (the set $z = \pm 1$), and it's a _smooth_ $1$-form if you remove the two poles and the semi-circular arc $\theta = 0$.